# Что содержит C# без .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, .net

В основном при разработке на C# используются библиотеки, входящие в состав .NET. 
Что содержит сам язык, если отбросить .NET?

Comment: содержит фигурные скобки и десяток ключевых слов?

Comment: Тоже что и все остальные языки без библиотек - синтаксис и необходимый алфавит. Исключение разве что Assembler, да чистый двоичный код. Ну может быть еще Си, т.к. он фактически по своим возможностям ближе к асму чем другие ЯП высокого уровня

Comment: Стандартная библиотека — часть языка. Она может быть имплементирована как в виде .NET Framework, так и без него (например, Mono).

Comment: @ VladD скорее не часть, а необходимое дополнение, поскольку формально, ЯП - это набор правил записи операций, а фактически на одних правилах далеко не уедешь и приходится тащить за собой стандартную библиотеку. И чем выше уровень языка, тем больше размер этой библиотеки.